# Поиск в тексте и выделение

Tags: javascript, php

Поиск производится в БД с помощью php по принципу MySQL запроса - `LIKE %{data}%`.

Допустим, что в БД записи с таким содержимым - `Login_012345`, `Login_000555`, `Login_100005`.

При отправке запроса на поиск "log" - выведутся все 3 записи.

При "`in_`" - аналогично.

Если "`00`" - выведет вторую и третью.

А вот если "`_0`" - будут выведены все 3.

Также и с "`___`" - все строки будут выведены.

Как реализовать подсветку найденного текста если был задан запрос формата "`___`"?

Или же как избежать такой возможности поиска с "`___`" и если введен запрос "`___`", то показывать только те записи, где реально есть "`___`"?

Comment: `_` - спецсимвол в MySQL в конструкции `LIKE`, который допускает любой символ вместо этого символа, поэтому и выводятся все три записи. Вы всегда можете просто экранировать подобные символы перед отправкой запроса (что следует делать всегда)

Comment: Либо переделайте вашу конструкцию с `LIKE` на `LOCATE('%data%', field) > 0`

Comment: @rusgeli, запрос в БД выполняется с помощью PDO (....LIKE ?", $data.....). Это же вроде подразумевает, что переменная обрабатывается? Я и пришел к выводу, что подчеркивание - это любой символ. Если не уходить от этой проблемы, а сделать решение? Как можно при запросе `___1` в найденной записи `Login_00012` выделить `0001` с помощью JS?

Comment: @rusgeli, в моей голове все очень тупо - посчитать количество символов, посчитать количество `_`, вырезать из поисковой фразы все `_` и найти позицию поисковой фразы без подчеркивания в тексте. Ну и дальше замена. Но это решение не красивое и тупое...

Comment: @DimaRRR, может и подразумевается(честно, не в курсе), что переменная обрабатывается, но спецсимвол не будет обработан, т.к. он может участвовать в запросе и нести ключевое значение. Чтобы он не обрабатывался как спецсимвол, вам достаточно перед каждым `_` поставить \ . В таком случае он не будет расценен как спецсимвол и будет восприниматься как обычный символ нижнего подчеркивания. Тогда вы сможете исключить некорректные варианты. А как сделать подсветку -- идей особых нет. Есть вариант обыграть это регуляркой, заменив в поисковой строке `_` соответствующую регуляркам конструкцию